# Invalid Token for JWT in Stormpath

Tags: php, token, jwt, stormpath, invalid-characters

I am using **Stormpath SDK** in a **PHP** application to generate **JWT** response. When handling the response I am getting the below error message.

Token is invalid *[developerMessage] => Token* is invalid because the issued at time (iat) is after the current time.

If someone can help me in resolving the issue that will be great. Also attached are 2 screenshots for the response we received.

Screen shot for Error1 :
 [image]

Screen shot for Error2 :
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: we need a lot more info before we can help.  Whilst the error is important, it would be handy to see some code.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the clock on your server and make sure your NTP is in sync. If it's drifted too far ahead, it could cause the kind of error you are seeing. Also, I work for Stormpath and our OPS team is looking into possible NTP drift on the backend. Are you using https://api.stormpath.com?

Comment: Quick follow up: all the clocks are sync'd on Stormpath's backend. Make sure your server's local time is correct. You might try the same code on a different machine to confirm. The tolerances are pretty tight for security reasons.